# google maps api integration with php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, maps

I need to develop this idea, I have a MYSql database in my site, with adress from some local bussines.

And i need to have a search box in the contact page, to let the user type his adress or city, for eg, and send that information to google maps api and recive the nearest local bussines from that adress...

The problem is than I dont even know how to start doing it, is there any places to look for a tutorial or something like that?

Thank you all, and sorry for the newbie and bad English.

Comment: Try this [article in the Google Maps Javascript API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on the same thing (except that I get the location of the user with html geolocation).

In general, these are the steps (I took):

1. If not present yet and if possible, add a latitude and longitude column in the mysql table for all addresses and calculate these values for each address. It will make it easier later on to filter addresses within a given range.
2. Get the latitude and longitude of the address the user gives in the input/search-box.
3. Define "nearest local business". How much km is it? If you have a certain amount, you can then create a boundary box for example with the code below (I use this code):

   $rad = 5;  // radius of bounding circle in kilometers

   $R = 6371;  // earth's mean radius, km

   // first-cut bounding box (in degrees)
     $maxLat = $_GET['lat'] + rad2deg($rad/$R);
     $minLat = $_GET['lat'] - rad2deg($rad/$R);
     // compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
     $maxLon = $_GET['long'] + rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($_GET['lat'])));
     $minLon = $_GET['long'] - rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($_GET['lat'])));
4. You can use variables minLat, maxLat, minLon, maxLon to filter out the addresses nearby in a mysql query calculate the [distance](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and put them in the order you like.
5. You can show these addresses as html but also as markers on the map.

[Please read the google map API tutorial.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) It was very helpful for me. The basic things I think you need to focus on are:

- How is the current data stored?
- Do I have the data I need (lat/lng) from the known addresses)?
- what will be the mysql query to get the nearest addresses based on
  the users' input?
- How do I show a map on      the webpage and how do I plot markers on
  this map?

I hope this gives you some guidance. I'm still learning a lot, but this is what I got so far. This tutorial learns you the very basic of showing a map on a webpage: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

Good luck!